# ROSSerial fails to sync with teensy device on ROS Noetic

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, ros, platformio, teensy

I am using teensy with rosserial + ROS Noetic/Ubuntu 20.04 on RASPI4. The teensy code is implemented with ros_lib on platformio (https://platformio.org/lib/show/5526/...). The program compiles fine and uploads successfully on port `/dev/ttyACM0`. However, when I do `rosrun rossserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=500000` then I get the sync failed error.

> [ERROR] [1612795964.166906]: Unable to sync with device; possible link
> problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro
> rosserial_python with groovy Arduino.

Things I have already tried:

a) Setting correct baudrate in `Serial.begin(500000)`

b) Disabling all `Serial.begin` and `Serial.print` statements

c) Setting baudrate of ros node `nh.gethardware()->setbaud(500000)` before `nh.init()`

d) Increasing the default buffer size to 1024 in ros.h of ros_lib
`typedef NodeHandle_<arduinohardware, 10,="" 10,="" 1024,="" 1024=""> NodeHandle;`

e) Tried the Arduino board instead of Teensy and the problem still remain.

However, nothing has worked so far.

Comment: I found out that the problem occurs when using rosserial in combination with servo library. However, I have still not been able to figure out the exact source of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The default baud rate for rosserial is 56700. For changing it you will need to do the following

Modify the include statement in the arduino code from

```
#include <ros.h>
```

to

```
#include "ros.h"
```

Add the following header files alongside the .ino/.pde file

#### ros.h

```
#ifndef _ROS_H_
#define _ROS_H_

#include "ros/node_handle.h"
#include "ArduinoHardware.h"

namespace ros
{
  typedef NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware> NodeHandle;
}

#endif
```

#### ArduinoHardware.h

```
#ifndef ROS_ARDUINO_HARDWARE_H_
#define ROS_ARDUINO_HARDWARE_H_

#if ARDUINO>=100
  #include <Arduino.h>
#else
  #include <WProgram.h>
#endif

#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#define SERIAL_CLASS HardwareSerial

class ArduinoHardware
{
  public:
    ArduinoHardware()
    {
      iostream = &Serial;
      baud_ = 500000;
    }
  
    void setBaud(long baud)
    {
      this->baud_= baud;
    }
  
    int getBaud()
    {
      return baud_;
    }

    void init()
    {
      iostream->begin(baud_);
    }

    int read()
    {
      return iostream->read();
    };

    void write(uint8_t* data, int length)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
      {
        iostream->write(data[i]);
      }
    }

    unsigned long time()
    {
      return millis();
    }

  protected:
    SERIAL_CLASS* iostream;
    long baud_;
};

#endif
```

In the ArduinoHeader.h file we defined above the iostream & the baud rate to be used is set using the constructor as shown below

```
ArduinoHardware()
    {
      iostream = &Serial;
      baud_ = 500000;
    }
```

as you are using teensy with USB the iostream will be `Serial`. If you are using the pins and not the USB it will vary from `Serial1` to `Serial8` as mentioned [here](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_uart.html). The baud rate of the teensy can be varied by varying the `baud_` here set to 500000.

This code is referenced from [Advanced Configuration for NodeHandle and ArduinoHardware](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/NodeHandle%20and%20ArduinoHardware)